# Sorting data based on time stored not working after getting deployed in node JS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, datetime, heroku

I developed a simple MERN stack application and for that one of the use case was that I wanted to sort my data based upon the time that I took from user (in my backend) and thus wrote the following code in my node.js backend for it:-

When the program execution comes to the condition where check1 and check2 both are present then when I am running the application on localhost (locally) then it is working correctly and giving desired output but when I deployed the application on heroku then that block of code is not giving the same/desired output for the same set of data.

With the exact same code why is this difference I am unable to figure out any solution/alternative way to this problem would be helpful.

```js
const allDays = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

const getCurrentDay = () => {
  let date = new Date();
  let daynum = date.getDay();
  return allDays[daynum];
}

const getCurrentHour = () => {
  return parseInt(new Date().getHours())
}

const sortSubject = (a, b) => {
  let day = getCurrentDay();

  let check1 = a.routine.find((obj) => {
    return obj.day === day;
  })

  let check2 = b.routine.find((obj) => {
    return obj.day === day;
  })

  if (check1 && check2) {
    const hours1 = check1.time.split(":")[0];
    const hours1 = check2.time.split(":")[0];

    const hrs1 = parseInt(hours1);
    const hrs2 = parseInt(hours2);
    const currHour = getCurrentHour();

    if (Math.abs(hrs1 - currHour) > Math.abs(hrs2 - currHour)) {
      return 1;
    }

    return -1;
  } else if (check1) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Here is the screenshot for reference:-

**On localhost**
[image: On localhost]

**Deployed Version**
[image: Deployed Version]

**Edit**
Here is the schema for my subject model:-

```js
const subjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"user",
        required:true
    },
    subName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    routine:{
        type: [{day:String,time:String,link:String}]
    }
});
```

Here is where I am calling the particular function when I fetched all the subjects of a user before sending it to the client I sort it

```js
router.get(
    "/getsubjects",
    authorizeuser,
    async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            //Find all the subjects of the logged in user
            const subjects = await Subject.find({user:req.user.id});
            subjects.sort(sortSubject);
            return res.json({subjects});
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({error:"Some Internal Error Occured"});
        }
    }
)
```

Here is an sample subject:-
[image]

Comment: Why so complicated? `const getCurrentHour = ()=> new Date().getHours();`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please show an example subject

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for suggesting a simpler syntax also I have added an example subject and schema and when it is called as you asked.

Comment: I meant add the example as an object to the snippet. Just [edit], scroll down and click edit above snippet. We want a [mcve]